# I am writing a code to generate a PWM wave in VHDL but I am getting a bad synchronous description error for the pwmout node

Tags: vhdl

assuming a full 0 to 15 count of the gclk to be one period of the output pwm wave,
   the pwmin reflects the duty cycle. as the count decreases from 15+1 to 0 first the 
   bufferreg value gets the pwmin value at the rising edge of the gclk and on each consecutive clock edge checks the countreg value and gives pwmout based on that

```
entity pwm is
port(gclk: in std_logic;
reset: in std_logic;
pwmin: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); --input reg to reflect the duty cycle
pwmout: out std_logic );
end pwm;

architecture Behavioral of pwm is
signal bufferreg,countreg: unsigned(3 downto 0);

signal count: integer:=16; -- count value for the one full cycle of PWM
begin
    process(gclk, reset, pwmin)
    begin
    case reset is --asynchronous reset 
    when '0' =>
            loop1: for count in 16 downto 0 loop --count is 15+1
                        if (rising_edge(gclk)) then --the buffer reg is loaded athe first clock edge
                                if (count=16) then
                                bufferreg<=unsigned(pwmin);
                                countreg<="0000";
                                else 
                                            if (countreg<=bufferreg) then
                                                        pwmout<='1'; --output high for on period
                                            elsif (countreg>bufferreg) then
                                                        pwmout<='0'; --output low for off period
                                            end if;
                                         countreg<=countreg+1 --updating of countreg
                                end if;
                         end if;
                     --next;
            end loop loop1;
    when others => 

    end case;   

end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write your code somewhat like the following:

```
process(gclk, reset)
begin
    if reset='1' then -- asynchronous reset, high active
       ...
    elsif rising_edge(gclk) then -- synchronous stuff on rising edge
        loop1: for count...
            ...
```

be aware that your "for count in 16 downto 0 loop" leads to 17 steps!